# How to fix a new variable within Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have inherited a report and have come across a syntax error. Being new to Power BI, I don't have the knowledge to resolve so if any has an idea how to fix, that would be greatly appreciated.

Customers = IF(status = "Active"; Sum(ID);BLANK())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those semicolons (;) should be commas (,)

```
Customers = IF(status = "Active", Sum(ID), BLANK())
```